# реализация работы плагинов на php

Tags: php

Начал изучать php и столкнулся с проблемой. Вот я хочу чтобы к моей странице можно было подключить любое количество плагинов. Я поместил это в каталог `plugins`, и выглядит это так.

```
plugins/
  isuki/
    isuki.php
  test/
    test.php
    data.php
```

Чтобы плагин заработал, в каталоге должен быть файл с таким же именем что и каталог. Это файл и является главным.
Я написал такой код, но он работает если плагин один, но если плагина два, то include уже не срабатывает. Вот код.

```
<?php

$pl = [];
$plugins_names = [];

$dir = dir ( "plugins/" );
while ( false !== ($plugin_dir = $dir->read( ))) {
    echo "plugins: $plugin_dir<br>";

    $file = "plugins/$plugin_dir/$plugin_dir.php";
    echo "$file<br>";
    include "$file";
     $plugin_name = $plugin_dir;
    if ( file_exists($file)) {
        $pl[$plugin_name] = 'init';
        $plugin_names[] = $plugin_name;
    }


}
$dir->close();

foreach ( $plugin_names as &$plugin ) {
    $func = $pl[$plugin];
    $func();
}
```

Comment: переменная `$plugin_name`. Где ей присваивается хоть какое-нибудь значение?

Comment: @ArchDemon да я исправил это в своем коде, этот пример я переделывал. допустим что plugin_name содержит название каталога плагина. но всё равно не работает.

Comment: Ну в своём коде вы может и исправили, а вопросе - нет. А я не телепат, чтобы увидеть что вы исправили, а что нет.

Comment: @ArchDemon исправил.

Comment: в массиве `$pl` все значения равны `init`. Вы в цикле вызываете функцию `init()` несколько раз. В чём смысл?

Comment: @ArchDemon я думал сначала что эта ссылка как нибудь сохраниться на функцию, которая будет подключена в include. но щас конечно понимаю, что она будет вызывать функцию, которая последняя. да вообще код не правильный, но как надо сделать, чтобы можно было использовать плагины?